# Как работает Quaternion Lerp?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код. Нужно, чтобы при входе в триггер MainPipe.Pipe плавно сбрасывал свой rotation с текущего значения на (0,0,0). Но rotation сбрасывается мгновенно. Ошибка, наверное, где то в методе Landing? По Lerp смотрела видео и документацию. Вроде бы, все правильно сделала, но ошибка где то есть, а я ее не вижу

```
 private float _landingSpeed = 0.5f;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)

{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(LandingCoroutine());
    }
}

IEnumerator LandingCoroutine()
{
    while (MainPipe.Pipe.transform.rotation.x != 0)
    {
        Landing();
    }

    if(MainPipe.Pipe.transform.rotation.x == 0)
    {
        StopCoroutine(LandingCoroutine());
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
}

private void Landing()
{
    Quaternion.Lerp(MainPipe.Pipe.transform.rotation, MainPipe.Pipe.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0), _landingSpeed);
}
```

Comment: `Вроде бы, все правильно` скорее все неправильно. Корутина. yield return перемести в цикл, условие (х == 0) можешь удалить, корутина сама завершится, если х != 0. Landing. Читай документацию внимательно. Quaternion.Lerp сам ничему значение не присваивает, он возвращает кватернион, который находится между кватернионами а и б в позиции т. `MainPipe.Pipe.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0)` то что перед = здесь вообще не нужно, оно должно находиться перед Q.Lerp. `rotation = Q.Lerp(rotation, zero, speed)` вот так. Если никто ответ не напишет, позже распишу как все должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо того, что я написал в комменте. Извне изменять состояние объекта (менять  поля и т.д.) не самая лучшая идея, т.к. его могут изменять из разных мест и понять откуда появился какой-то баг будет сложнее. Он должен сам свое состояние изменять.

Что-то вроде:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Pipes
{
    public class Pipe : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [Header("Angles/second")]
        [SerializeField] private float _landingRotationSpeed = 10f;

        private Quaternion _landingRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        private IEnumerator _landingCoroutine = null;

        public void Land()
        {
            if (_landingCoroutine == null)
            {
                _landingCoroutine = Rotate(_landingRotation, _landingRotationSpeed);
                StartCoroutine(_landingCoroutine);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator Rotate(Quaternion rotation, float speed)
        {
            while (transform.rotation != rotation)
            {
                var newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

                transform.rotation = newRotation;

                yield return null;
            }

            _landingCoroutine = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Теперь не нужно изменять rotation извне, достаточно вызвать метод Land, чтобы его вращение обнулилось. Вот так:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Pipes
{
    public class LandingZone : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.TryGetComponent(out Pipe pipe))
            {
                pipe.Land();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При входе в триггер, пытаемся получить компонент Pipe и вызвать метод Land. И не нужно никаких Mainpipe.pipe.transform.rotation...........

Если так нужен Lerp, то замени в этой строке `var newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);` RotateTowards на Lerp, соответственно speed нужно будет ограничить от 0 до 1.